# "Import" doesn't work on the spec file on Cypress

Tags: import, cypress

If someone could help me on this please.

I have created page objects with the following code:

```
class Login {

  username(){
    return cy.get('#UserName').type('test1')
  }
  password(){
    return cy.get('#password-field').type('test2')
  }
  loginbtn(){
    return cy.get('.btn').click()
  }
  
}
```

export default Login

Here I have created class Login and imported on the spec file as:

```
import Login from '../support/PageObjects/Login'

    beforeEach('Login to shipment page',() => {

        cy.Login()

})
```

This was working before but now this is not working and I get the error (on hover) telling "Login is declared but it's value is never read." I have changed nothing. I am facing this issue many times but never got the proper solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object of the class `Login` and using that you can access the different methods. So your code should look like this:

```js
import Login from '../support/PageObjects/Login'
const login = new Login()
beforeEach('Login to shipment page', () => {
  login.username()
  login.password()
  login.loginbtn()
})
```

Answer (score 4):

This has to be something to do with your custom command `cy.Login()`, I imagine the code for it to be something like below:

```js
// cypress/support/commands.js

const login = new require('../PageObjects/Login.js')

Cypress.Commands.add('Login', () => {
  login.username()
  login.password()
  login.loginbtn()
})
```

Now that of course needs to be imported into `cypress/support/e2e.js`, but that is the default - check it anyway.

```js
// cypress/support/e2e.js

import './commands.js'
```

If you are using the Typescript, options are similar.

By the way, what is the file you are having the error from? I suspect that will give a clue.

Comment: I was having error on the spect file (test file)

Answer (score 4):

The login is not needed to be imported when you have a custom command like `cy.Login()`.

That is why the error occurs:

> 'Login' is declared but it's value is never read.

Custom commands are global to all tests and never need importing. The Login page is being added to the tests via `cy.Login()` and you can remove the import without affecting it.